# Can an insert procedure trigger unintentional loops?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible for a stored procedure like this to produce a loop of unintentional inserts? I'm asking since this exact procedure produces [this resulting loop](http://elections.gisslen.net/Results.aspx?seats=1&candidates=6&votes=50). (I'm pretty convinced it isn't within the server code, since all it has is a do until-loop that produces a perfect iteration). If I run the containing select-statement alone it works like a charm, but when I add the insert-line to the procedure it starts to repeat the inserts. I'm using MySQL server version: 5.0.83-community.

**EDIT** [There's a fiddle of this to play with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d95f/6).

```
DROP PROCEDURE `RedistributeEliminations`//
CREATE PROCEDURE `RedistributeEliminations`(IN current_round INT(11), IN votes_id CHAR(50), IN preferred_candidates CHAR(50), IN eliminated_candidates CHAR(50))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO vote_final (round_id, vote_candidate, redistribution, votes)
        SELECT current_round round_id, y.vote_candidate, y.redistribution, (votes + y.redistribution) votes
        FROM (
            (SELECT vote_candidate, COUNT(*) redistribution, t4.original_votes votes
            FROM vote_orders t1
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT ij1.vote_id, MIN(ij1.vote_order) min_vote_order
                FROM vote_orders ij1
                WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ij1.vote_candidate, eliminated_candidates) = 0
                AND FIND_IN_SET(ij1.vote_candidate, preferred_candidates) != 0
                AND FIND_IN_SET(ij1.vote_id, votes_id) != 0
                GROUP BY ij1.vote_id
            ) t2
            ON t1.vote_id = t2.vote_id
            AND t1.vote_order = t2.min_vote_order
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT ij2.vote_id
                FROM vote_orders ij2
                WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ij2.vote_candidate, eliminated_candidates) != 0
                AND FIND_IN_SET(ij2.vote_candidate, preferred_candidates) = 0
                AND ij2.vote_order = 1
            ) t3
            ON t1.vote_id = t3.vote_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT oj1.vote_candidate candidate, oj1.votes original_votes
                FROM vote_final oj1
                WHERE oj1.round_id = current_round - 1
            ) t4
            ON t1.vote_candidate = t4.candidate
            GROUP BY vote_candidate
            ORDER BY vote_candidate ASC)
            UNION
            (SELECT vote_candidate, (0 - COUNT(*)) redistribution, COUNT(*) votes
            FROM vote_orders
            WHERE vote_order = 1
            AND FIND_IN_SET(vote_candidate, eliminated_candidates) != 0
            AND FIND_IN_SET(vote_candidate, preferred_candidates) = 0
            GROUP BY vote_candidate)
            UNION
            (SELECT vote_candidate, 0 redistribution, votes
            FROM vote_final
            WHERE round_id = current_round - 1)
        ) y
        GROUP BY y.vote_candidate;
END
```

Comment: Has the table `vote_final` a trigger? And can you add your `CREATE TABLEs` scripts and some sample data, for help you.

Comment: Of course. I'll add it for you to test within the hour! :)

Comment: I think I've managed to boil it down to something grabbable [in this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d95f/6). Unfortunately I don't know how to get the fiddle to run the procedure - maybe you know how to trigger it? And hopefully it then produces the same error as the site I referenced to in my question. :)

Comment: This is what I got: https://gist.github.com/onare/e05d36d38ae69aab5566 , what's your expect output? (I ran the query inside `RedistributeEliminations` and that sp returns 2 rows.

Comment: I expect a result where the vote_final table is extended with 6 rows below the original ones. The complete redistribution column should contain these value (rows) 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,1,0,0,0 and the complete votes-column should contain these values (rows) 8,1,2,4,2,3,8,0,3,4,2,3.